# Is it possible to get the child elements of a WKInterfaceGroup programmatically?

Tags: ios, watchkit, wkinterfacegroup

Rather than Ctrl + dragging from interface builder, is there a way to access the child elements of a WKInterfaceGroup programmatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, WatchKit doesn't allow you to access interface objects properties programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

No. You must use outlets for this.